# Conditional operator not giving correct output

Tags: c++

We have an issue that I have been able to recreate with this sample code:

```
int main()
{
  double d = -2;
  // ...
  cout << "d: " << d << endl;
  cout << "-d: " << -d << endl;
  
  cout << "Conditional Operator (expect value 2): " << (d < 0)? -d : d;
  cout << endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

---

The output is as follows:

```
d: -2
-d: 2
Conditional Operator (expect value 2): 1
```

Comment: It's just about operator precedence: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42840519e1dde0cc merely a typo, that's why I down and close voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).  Use:

```
cout << "Conditional Operator (expect value 2): " << (d < 0? -d : d);
```

**Explanations:**

The reason is that `<<` has a higher precedence than `?` So your orignal statement does not mean what you expect, i.e.

```
cout << "Conditional Operator (expect value 2): " << ( (d < 0)? -d : d );
```

but

```
(cout << "Conditional Operator (expect value 2): " <<  (d < 0) ) ? -d : d ;
```

So `cout` outputs `(d<0)` after the string.  Since the expression is true it results as output 1, unless you'd have used `cout << std::boolalpha <<...`, in which case it would have printed `true`.

The printing is then finished and `(cout<<...<<...)` is then used as condition for the ternary operator, but the final result is lost, as it is not part of the cout expression and nothing is done with that result.

Comment: Good explanation but can you also explain where the value 1 is coming from?

Comment: @Sandeep I've edited the answer with the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
  cout << "Conditional Operator (expect value 2): " << (d < 0 ? -d : d);
```

Besides, you could just use

```
  cout << "Conditional Operator (expect value 2): " << std::abs(d);
```

`std::abs` calculates the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of a number, and functionally, your code does the same thing anyways

Comment: Good explanation but can you also explain where the value 1 is coming from?